# Replace more than one forward slash

Tags: php

I'd like to replace more than one forward slash with one forward slash.

Examples:

`this/is//an//example` -> `this/is/an/example`

`///another//example////` -> `/another/example/`

`example.com///another//example////` -> `example.com/another/example/`

Thanks!

EDIT: This will be used to fix URLs that have more than one forward slash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
preg_replace('#/+#','/',$str);
```

or

```
preg_replace('#/{2}#','/',$str);
```

**Tips:** use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)  for such a simple replacement AS it

> replace all occurrences of the search string with the replacement string

```
str_replace('/','/',$str);
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly, plus you gave two different ways to do it.

Comment: Accept as an answer if it is worthy :)

Comment: I need to wait another 4 minutes before I can accept an answer.

Comment: The second option wouldn't work for cases with more than two '/' like example.com///another//example//// right?

Comment: @diEcho I've tried with test/// and it ends up doing test// --

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use regex:

```
$modifiedString = preg_replace('|/{2,}|','/',$strToModify);
```

I use the `{2,}` instead of `+` to avoid replacing single '/'.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to replace one or more /-es with /:

```
$string = preg_replace('#/+#', '/', $string);
```

I see you want to create a valid url... you might want to check out [realpath](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php), or maybe even better the snippet in the first comment:

```
$path = '../gallery/index/../../advent11/app/';

$pattern = '/\w+\/\.\.\//';
while(preg_match($pattern, $path)) {
    $path = preg_replace($pattern, '', $path);
}
// $path == '../advent11/app/'
```

As you can see this also solves ../-es :)